# WiFI не работает в AVD Android Emualtor

Tags: android, эмулятор, avd

Запускаю приложение в эмуляторе AVD, приложение вылетает. AVD android 7.0

Как быть? Если без интернета то работает все нормально. Да и WiFI не включить ни как. Его там нету просто навсего... Кто сталкивался с таким?

Как решить такую проблему.

Comment: С каким исключением валетает? Какие параметры AVD?

Comment: Ошибок в логах вообще никаких нет.

Comment: Работает ли приложение на Android 5.0? Начиная с 6-й версии появились "runtime permissions", https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-hardware-id Вы запрашиваете разрешение на вай-фай во время работы приложения?

Comment: Неа. Но а разве Exception не должен появиться если permision нет. А тут вообще в логах пустота

Comment: @Roman, Просто запустите AVD емулятор Android 7.0 или 6.0 и запустите любое приложение с интернетом. У вас приложение также вылетит